# Получение числа из html в android

Tags: android, webview

Есть android приложение с WebView, в котором открывается html страница с одним числом. Нужно получить это число и записать в переменную.

Comment: Покажите, что уже сделали.

Comment: Ничего особенного: самый простой пример, который загружает заданную страницу в WebView. сторона сервера отправляет уже даже не html а простое число от 0 до 1024 и это число нужно записать в переменную для дальнейших действий

Comment: используйте jsoup

Answer (score 1):

Если в лоб - берете полученную строку и извлекаете необходимое число. Можете использовать регулярные выражения, можете при помощи `indexOf` вырезать число из текста между тегами (или в каком виде приходит строка)

Comment: С извлечением числа проблем нет: вся страница состоит из одного числа (никаких тегов, заголовков) я не могу понять как получить и записать строку